# Can i retrieve information other than username/Identity from bearer token Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I am pretty much new to token base authentication. Can i read other than username from ClaimsPrincipal principal (identity). Is there any way to read/write(store) other information in bearer token.

```
ClaimsPrincipal principal = Request.GetRequestContext().Principal as ClaimsPrincipal;

var Name = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: the token is a jwt if you decrypt it you can read whats in it.     As for writing to it that really should be left to the identity server and oauth server as thats its job.

Comment: Thank you @DalmTo

Comment: If you want more info about the user see if you can find the userinfo end point for the login server you are using.

Comment: @DaImTo Good point. Of course the JWT should not be overloaded with too much additional information. A userinfo endpoint is a good solution, we also do it this way in our application.

Comment: @jps there is actually a limit to the size of a bearer token due to the max length of request headers so adding extra data to the claims is really not a good idea.

Comment: @DaImTo yes, there's a limit, usually somewhere around 8k, so the general advice not to put too much extra payload in the JWT makes sense, but I would not go so far to rule this out completely. You would need really a lot of extra payload to reach the limit.

Comment: Another consideration would be if the data could change during the lifetime of the token in question.   You will have out of sync data.   (dealing with this issue currently to much stuff in token set by my predecessor)

Comment: You gays have mention really good points here. I think using service end point for login server is better way than load extra data to token. Otherwise i have to consider about sync data within token life time. I think it will effect to performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Additional information is stored is so called claims in the payload part of a JWT.
JWT is described in [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) and [section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4) of this rfc describes the standard claims as well as the possibility to use private claim names.

The JWT issuer (the authorization server) can also write addional claims to the JWT, e.g.:

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("JWT");  

identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName)); // standard claim
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("myClaim", "myClaimValue")); // private claim
```

Please note: only the issuer can add information to the JWT and it can only be done during the creation of the JWT.

As the payload of a JWT is just normal JSON (after base64 decoding), you can read all the claims.

Check https://jwt.io/ for examples.

Comment: Thank you @jps. Very helpful. JWT issuer is the point that i have stuck previously. I will try with your infirmation.

Comment: Glad to help. Yes, the JWT issuer is the only one who can add information and only when he creates the JWT.

Answer (score 2):

You can get any value from your bearer token with key like "user_name".

```
private string GetUserName()
{       
    var claims = (ClaimsIdentity)ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity;

    if (claims == null)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }

    var targetClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "user_name");
    if (targetClaim == null)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }

    return targetClaim.Value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @S.Poline. As your code sample we need to add new claim type in JWT issuer named "user_name" and then we can read values from bearer token. Am i right?